# Format SQL Server 2012 Time(7) to "HH:mm"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, format

I have `Time(7)` columns for each day in the week and I want to format it as `HH:mm`

[image]

I tried to use SQL Server 2012 new `FORMAT` function, but it only shows the `NULL` value.

[image]

How can I format a `time(7)` datatype to display as `HH:mm`?

Comment: Every time I see a question about formatting SQL Server dates/times I ask the same thing: Why do you need to do this? Can you not format it in your user interface?

Comment: Just saying... this is usually a presentation concern, and can usually be done trivially in your app code... why are you trying to do presentation logic in the database?

Comment: It depends on what is your interface.  I am displaying it in SSRS and I cannot do the formatting to the Time datatype there.

Comment: @TTCG I've not tried to display a TIME datatype in SSRS, but if it really doesn't work I'd cast it to DATETIME and then it will work.

Comment: Sometimes you might just want to display the results of an ad-hoc query in a grid on the front-end without having to write code in the front-end to format things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always format your data in the presentation layer.  If there are circumstance where the TIME datatype cannot be formatted by your UI, you can cast the value to a DATETIME which will more than likely be supported.

```
SELECT CAST(TimeColumn AS DATETIME)
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 5):

Format does work on time(7), but you have to escape the colon and hh mm are lower case.

```
Declare @HourMonday as  time(7) = '13:45:00'

Select FORMAT(@HourMonday, N'hh\:mm')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Format in Ms-sql** To Get Format of Time as you Need

**Example :**

```
SELECT Format(GETDATE(), 'hh:mm')
```

**Output :**

```
07:52
```

For You Columns You can **Replace `GETDATE()` with your column name** as below -

**Example :**

```
SELECT Format(HourMonday, 'hh:mm')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT left(TimeColumn,5) as Time
FROM MyTable
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c2a4/1

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mytime Time(7)
set  @mytime=GETDATE()
select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(50),CAST(@mytime as time)),1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit to the already chosen answer.

Since you are using Reporting Services you can do the formatting with Format():

```
=Format(Now(), "hh:mm")
```

Comment: Yes, I did.  It works only for DateTime data types.  It does not work for the Time Data Type.  So, you need to cast as the DateTime as shown in the chosen answer or cast(TimeColumn AS VARCHAR(5)) to get HH:mm time format.