# How to change SQL Server time(7) format (hh:mm tt) in datagridview control c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datetime, datagridview

I checked this link 
[Format SQL Server 2012 Time(7) to "HH:mm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214052/format-sql-server-2012-time7-to-hhmm)

but I want to change the format in C#.

Like this

```
dgvRoster.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Format = "hh:mm tt" };
```

This line of code works on `datetime` datatype of SQL Server.

I try to change datatype `DateTime` to `time(7)` and `time(0)` both but cause [THIS EXCEPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX5kY.png) on those lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Overflow Answer to a similar case in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432552/how-do-i-display-time-column-as-hhmm-tt-in-datagridview-which-is-retrieved-from)

> .NET accepts the TIME datatype as System.TimeSpan not System.DateTime.
>
> Here you are trying to assign custom DateTime format, that why you get
>   error as "Input string was not in a correct format".
>
> You need to assign custom TimeSpan format, like
>
> dataGridView1.Columns[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432552/how-do-i-display-time-column-as-hhmm-tt-in-datagridview-which-is-retrieved-from).DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"hh:mm";
>
> Check this link to know more about custom TimeSpan format
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx
>
> By default, TimeSpan doesn't support 12hr time format.
>
> You need to convert TimeSpan to DateTime object and specify any custom
>   DateTime format as you want.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx#The):

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals. For example, "dd.hh:mm" defines a period (.) as the separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator between hours and minutes.

You will have to use `\\:` instead of `:` for this.

The second issue is the `tt` which is not supported by `TimeSpan`

So, either you keep the datatype as `DateTime`, or change the format to `Format = @"hh\:mm"`

Comment: thank you this format @"hh\:mm" working but i need AM / PM too.

Comment: You will have to use `datetime` then

Comment: does sql server and .net not any compatible type for this format "hh:mm tt"    
 except datetime  (because there is no need to date this is garbage for me )?